# how to login user through code in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I have to login a user through drupal code having userID... basically the scenario is that I have registered a user through e-mail verification. when user clicks the link given in email he/she become active. Now I need to implement that along with becoming user active, he/she should be logged in automatically. I think i made my point clear. Any idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the User module, specifically the [user_external_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_external_login/6) and [user_authenticate_finalize](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_authenticate_finalize/6) functions. You can either call those functions or use them as the basis for creating your own functions.

On a related note, there's not enough detail in your question to know for sure, but it sounds like you might be duplicating functionality already in the User module. If you're new to Drupal, you may want to make sure you can't accomplish what you need to do with the existing options under User management > User settings.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for reply. Yes, I am new to drupal. Now I decided to go with logintoboggan module. It works fine for me except one functionality. I need to remove links for "Create new account" and "Request new password" in login module. yes I can hide these with css but I need to hide them through proper channel. Can you help in this regard?

Comment: That sounds unrelated to your original question. I'd suggest opening a separate question.

Comment: Yes, Its a different one. I'll open a new question for it. Thanks for direction. Talking about original one, I've created a user registration module. When user is registered initially its status is not active(0) in users table. And an email(with some url) is sent to his given address to activate his account. Now when user clicks the link it status become 1. I have implemented a php code in block for all of this. Now I need that when user clicks the link provided in email, his status must be 1 and user must logged in automatically. I have user Id available in that block of code.